# Reading Only Part of a File in C

Tags: c, text

I'm trying to make a program for myself that will add up numbers from a .txt file. Let's say my file looks like this:

```
0004    78  118
0014    79  118
0024    79  119
0034    77  119
0044    76  118
0054    76  117
0064    77  118
0074    75  119
0084    80  121
0094    81  122
```

The problem I am encountering is that I have decided I want to be able to add only the numbers from one of the columns at a time and am having trouble figuring out a way of doing so. Does anyone have any ideas on how I would, for example, only add up all the numbers from the 2nd column? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

`%*s` = read one string separated by whitespaces and throw it away

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE* fp;
    int sum = 0, data;
    fp = stdin; /* or open the file you want to deal with */
    while (fscanf(fp, "%*s%d%*s", &data) == 1) {
        sum += data;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    printf("sum = %d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Short and simple and does exactly what I want. Much appreciated. I changed 'fp = stdin;' to 'fp = fopen("BP_1.txt", "r");' to suit my purposes. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper function that selects the column you wish to read;

```
// 1: Success
// 0: Ill formatted data
// EOF: No more data
int read_column(int index, int *value) {
  char buf[100];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) return EOF;
  int d[3];
  if (sscanf("%d%d%d", &d[0], &d[1], &d[2]) != 3) return 0;
  *value = d[index];
  return 1;
}
```